# UINavigationBar does not extend behind status bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

I feel like I'm completely overlooking something, since this is so basic.

In a completely bare bones setup:

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
window.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

let rootController = MainViewController()
rootNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootController)

window.rootViewController = rootNavigationController;
window.makeKeyAndVisible()

// Appearance
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.DailyRate.blueColor
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
UINavigationBar.appearance().opaque = false
```

I get a navigation bar that does *not* extend behind the status, which should be default behavior.

[image]

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by DailyRate in UIColor property? I did not see the that property in IOS swift .

Comment: It's a UIColor extension

Comment: Please try my bellow code and see the result. Did you change anything in plist or viewcontrioller anywhere ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that it was a timing issue.

The root hierarchy was actually set up in the initializer of a separate class called `UIManager`. However, this class was initialized at the same time as the `AppDelegate`

```
var uiManager = UIManager()
```

and **not** in `application(_, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions _)` method, thus creating this weird scenario.

So all I did was

```
var uiManager: UIManager?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    uiManager = UIManager()

}
```

And now everything is back to normal.

Thanks to @govindarao-kondala for planting the right idea in my head!

Answer (score 1):

I just tried and I got proper result. Please find my complete code. I  can not find few things in your code(I don't get what you mean by **DailyRate**) , remaining things are same as your code.

```
var window: UIWindow?
    var rootNavigationController : UINavigationController?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {


    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    let rootController = ViewController()
    rootNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootController)

    window!.rootViewController = rootNavigationController;
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    // Appearance
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
    UINavigationBar.appearance().opaque = false

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```

And the result is in following attachment. [image]

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem because I was removing the built-in line border at the bottom of the navigation bar, like this:

```
if let navigationBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {
    navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
    navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
}
```

I was doing the above code inside my view controller's `viewWillAppear` because some of my VCs have other colors for the navigation bar and I don't want to modify the universal appearance.

The solution was to just create a 1 pt x 1 pt image with the color I want and use it instead of a new empty `UIImage` instance, like this:

```
if let navigationBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {
    let colorImage = UIImage.imageWithColor(self.category.color)
    navigationBar.shadowImage = colorImage
    navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(colorImage, forBarMetrics: .Default)
    navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
```

`imageWithColor` is a function I defined in an extension to `UIImage`:

```
class func imageWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
    let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor)
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect)

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```